# Calculating large powers of 2 in decimal

Tags: c#, algorithm

So, this is my problem to solve:

I want to calculate \$2^n\$ where \$0 < n< 10000\$

I am representing each element of array as a space where 4digit number should be "living" and if extra digit appears, I am replacing it to the next element of this array.

The principle I am using looks like this:

[image]

The code I am using is the following:

```
static string NotEfficient(int power)
{
if (power < 0)
    throw new Exception("Power shouldn't be negative");
if (power == 0)
    return "1";
if (power == 1)
    return "2";

int[] A = new int[3750];

int current4Digit = 0;

//at first 2 is written in first element of array
A[current4Digit] = 2;

int currentPower = 1;

while (currentPower < power)
{
    //multiply every 4digit by 2
    for (int i = 0; i <= current4Digit; i++)
    {
        A[i] *= 2;
    }

    currentPower++;

    //checking every 4digit if it
    //contains 5 digit and if yes remove and 
    //put it in next 4digit
    for (int i = 0; i <= current4Digit; i++)
    {
        if (A[i] / 10000 > 0)
        {
            int more = A[i] / 10000;
            A[i] = A[i] % 10000;
            A[i + 1] += more;

            //if new digit should be opened
            if (i + 1 > current4Digit)
            {
                current4Digit++;
            }

        }


    }
}

//getting data from array to generate answer
string answer = "";

for (int i = current4Digit; i >= 0; i--)
{
    answer += A[i].ToString().PadLeft(4,'0') + ",";
}

return return answer.TrimStart('0');
}
```

Comment: reminds me of [Calculate 2ⁿ where 0<n<10000](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50708800) - what are you looking for in a *code review*, what is to be the *measure* for `better`?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

> How I can make this algorithm better?

Here's how I would make your algorithm better.

First: your principle is sound. You are displaying a large binary number in base 10 by taking advantage of the fact that `int` already has a method that displays a 32 bit number in base 10.  Essentially your method is:

- convert the number to base 10000, by making an int array "digits" from 0 to 9999.
- Make a device which can double one of those numbers
- Print the result after the given number of doublings.

This technique works, but your implementation could use some improvements. The improvements I would make are:

- Go big!  Why base 10000?  You could do base 100000000 in an int no problem or base 1000000000000000000 in a long.  Let's do that.
- You allocate a huge number of ints.  That's probably either way too many or way too few for the problem at hand.  Don't limit yourself. Make a solution that grows as you need it, not one that has an arbitrary limit.  Moreover: you make 3750 ints, but you could do the entire problem with only 167 longs.
- Abstract away your operations into a type that represents the value
- Refactor each part of the algorithm into a helper method that does one thing well.
- Stop using mutable state. It's OK to burn a little memory. The garbage collector will deal.
- Use a more efficient algorithm to calculate big powers.

How might we put these principles into practice? Let's try.

First off, I'm going to make a struct which represents a number encoded in base 1000000000000000000.  Its implementation will be a list of longs, but it could be any collection type. Lists are just convenient.

(Aside: **Why a struct?** The implementation is small; it's a wrapper around a single reference. The meaning of the struct is logically a *value*.  It is *immutable*.  So this is a good candidate for a value type.  We get the benefits of having a clean interface and implementation hiding, but we only pay the price of a single reference.)

```
struct Base1000000000000000000
{
    private List<long> digits;
    private Base1000000000000000000(List<long> digits) {
        this.digits = digits;
    }
```

Note that so far everything is private. I want this to have a very locked-down interface.  We've got to get this party started somewhere, so let's represent one:

```
  public static readonly Base1000000000000000000 One = 
    new Base1000000000000000000(new List<long> { 1L });
```

You could do `Zero` similarly.

Now what does our display algorithm look like? That's a one-liner:

```
public override string ToString() =>
    string.Join("",
        ((IEnumerable<long>)digits)
          .Reverse()
          .Select(d => d.ToString().PadLeft(18, '0')));
```

Note that we're using the non-destructive reverse, not the destructive reverse on list.

The core of the algorithm is in our adder, which takes a number and returns its double:

```
  public Base1000000000000000000 DoubleIt() 
  { 
    // Note, _ separators in constants are new for C# 7.
    const long TheBase = 1_000_000_000_000_000_000;
    var result = new List<long>();
    result.Add(0);
    for (int i = 0; i < this.digits.Count; i += 1)
    {
      // Make sure we have storage.
      if (i == result.Count)
        result.Add(0);
      result[i] += this.digits[i] + this.digits[i];
      // We might have to carry.
      if (result[i] >= TheBase)
      {
        // Again, make sure we have room.
        if (i + 1 == result.Count)
          result.Add(0);
        result[i+1] = result[i] / TheBase;
        result[i] -= TheBase;
      }
    }
    // And we're done.
    return new Base1000000000000000000(result);
  }
```

Super.  Now the main algorithm is straightforward:

```
Base1000000000000000000 c = Base1000000000000000000.One;
for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
  c = c.DoubleIt();
return c.ToString();
```

**Notice how when I extract each operation to its own method, the code becomes simpler and more elegant**.

Now, how can you improve this further?

- *Exercise*: (Easy) Implement `operator+` on this type.
- *Exercise*: (Pretty Easy) Implement `operator-` on this type, and represent negative numbers correctly.
- *Exercise*: (Hard) Implement `operator*` on this type.
- *Exercise*: (Very hard) Now that you have multiplication and addition, you can get to 2<sup>n</sup> much faster. Suppose you want to do 2<sup>384</sup>.  Start with `One`.  Double it.  Now you have 2<sup>1</sup>.  Multiply it by itself -- square it.  Now you have 2<sup>2</sup>.  Square it again to get 2<sup>4</sup>. Square it again to get 2<sup>8</sup>.  And so on, until you have them up to 2<sup>256</sup>.  Multiply 2<sup>256</sup> by 2<sup>128</sup> to get 2<sup>384</sup>, and you're done.  Your original algorithm does 384 doublings, but you can get the answer with one doubling and nine multiplies. **Can you work out the algorithm for the optimal sequence of multiplications and additions**?
- *Exercise* (Very hard): Implement `%` and `/` on this type.
- *Exercise* (Very very hard): Now do it all over again **without using any built-in type for the math**. (Obviously use `string` for the text.)  You are leveraging the ability of `int` or `long` to represent a bitfield that can be displayed in base 10.  What if you didn't have that?  Because **someone had to write that code**. The person who wrote that code didn't have it because it hadn't been written yet.  Suppose C# didn't have any integer type; how would you implement math from scratch?

Comment: Very small nitpick: I think this would be more readable if instead of `1000000000000000000L` you'd have a variable with this value and write it using digit separators: `1000_000_000_000_000_000L`.

Comment: To be fair that's new to C#7, he might target lower version.

Comment: @germi: That's a good suggestion, thanks. I would put the value in a *constant* and not a *variable*.

Comment: @EricLippert even better ;)